# TypeError: endturn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, self

My class function is not working. I am kind of new to classes and I am trying to understand the error message. I am not sure if i am going to put anything in the parameters?

```
class turns():

    def endturn(self):
        global movePoints
        print("Turn Ended: \nRecruitment Report: {}".format(Recruited))
        movePoints = 20

x = 50
y = 50
speed = 10
movePoints = 20
movePointLost = 1
Recruited = 0

turns.endturn()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to create an instance of your class

```
t = turns()
t.endturn()
```

Usually it doesn't make sense to call instance methods in the class directly.

Comment: You *could* if you did `turns.endturns(turns)` but there'd be no access to instance variables.

Comment: @NChauhan Or either with `@staticmethod` decorator.